# PHP PDO: Constant Variable at End of SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I can't seem to figure this one out, I'm trying to globalize all of the database credentials across my application , therefore I'm setting the database table name in a global constants file.  I have one query that no matter how many ways I try to set the constant variable in the string, it fails miserably.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the query before the constant variable change, which works:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM crmManager");
```

Here's a few different attempts that all fail (the constant variable is TBL_NAVIGATION):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM " . TBL_NAVIGATION . ");    
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM".TBL_NAVIGATION.");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM".TBL_NAVIGATION);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM {TBL_NAVIGATION}");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM".TBL_NAVIGATION");
```

I even tried to set it initially as a variable:

```
$table = TBL_NAVIGATION;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM {table}"); 
 // I've tried every possible way to include the variable
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: you have some typo's in your example code. (unclosed string quotes; missing space after FROM) Is this your actual code or just some mistake when pasting it here?

Comment: did you try something simple as `echo "TBL_NAVIGATION: " . TBL_NAVIGATION . PHP_EOL;` right before your prepare statement? In other words: are you 100% sure the constant is really available? I can only imagine a typo and/or include problem.

Comment: Well slap me silly, an obvious oversight on my part, a good indicator that I shouldn't stay up this late! `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM ".TBL_NAVIGATION)` was the answer, had a missing space. Thanks Kaii!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need " after constant.

```
"SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM " . TBL_NAVIGATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check your syntax is the lesson to be learned here:

The correct query was:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT MAX(salesPosition) FROM ".TBL_NAVIGATION);
```

Thanks to Kaii for waking me up!